# How to Secure Data Submitted Through CKEditor

Tags: php, security, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my site to let the users post their comments. CKEditor has many buttons to compose the comment. Suppose If a User makes his comment bold and italic Such Like

***`This is comment`***

And CKEditor will ouput the following html

```
<i><strong>This is comment</strong></i>
```

Now, If I store this html in the mysql database and output on the webpage as it is, without wrapping it with htmlspecialchars(), then The Comment will be shown on the page bold and italic and this is what I want.

But on the other hand If I wrap the comment with htmlspecialchars() and displays it on the webpage it will be shown as

```
<i><strong>This is comment</strong></i>
```

But I do not want to show like this, I want the user formatting. But If I do not wrap it with  htmlspecialchars(), it is risky and it can cause XSS Attack and other security risks.

How Can I Achieve both Purposes 
(1). Keep the User Formatting 
(2). Also Secure the HTML Contents

Comment: you can use mysql_real_escape_string()  at the time of insertion if you want to Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @ajay Actually, I am not worried about the SQL Injection. I am worried about the XSS Attack.

Comment: yes htmlspecialchars() is better way to prevent XSS attack. but we can't use it in case of CKEditor. than we can use addslashes(),stripslashes(),strip_tags() functions.

Answer (score 4):

You need to draw up a whitelist of what elements and attributes you want to allow your users to include (eg allow `<strong>` but not `<script>`; allow `<a href>` but not `<div onmouseover>`), and then enforce it by parsing the input, removing all elements and attributes that don't fit your pattern, and serialising the results back into HTML.

This is a hard job that cannot be done with a few simple regexes or `strip_tags` (which is NOT an adequate solution for XSS even if it did fit your needs). You would be well advised to use an existing library to do it - [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is one such for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags` function has option to allow or disallow tags. use php.net for more reference about strip tags. You must strip unwanted or not allowed tags. if you don't then it might be vunerable by javascripts too.

Use `htmlspecialchars` while u are storing and use `htmlspecialchars_decode` while you are displaying.  This will help you to keep format of user formated content

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for `strip_tags`. it will remove all the html and php tags from the string and only allow the given tags like `<strong><i>` etc

```
<?php 
$str = "<i><strong>this is a comment<strong></i><script>here is script</script>";
echo $str = strip_tags($str,"<i><strong>");
 ?>
```

[php.net documentation for strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

Two options spring to mind. First of all you can strip out all HTML and use a BB code parser to allow the user to post BB tags, rather than HTML - http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Secondly, you could strip out all HTML except a few tags. I don't know of any parser that does that personally, however I have seen it in action on sites before (Murphy's law I can't find any right now). You should be able to achieve this with a sophisticated enough RegEx replacement check.

Comment: Actually I don't want to use BBCode. Can I strip some specific tags like <script> etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use this before printing it back on screen:

```
 function html_escape($raw_input)
        {
            return htmlspecialchars($raw_input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');     
        }
```